# animating a cell when pressed affects other cells

Tags: swift

[image]

I want to animate a card when pressed.
I made a table view, and added a custom cell to it.
and in custom cells, I created a UIButton and applied .touchUpInside gesture on the button.
when the button is pressed, the background color of the card will turn to red.

but weird thing is, if I press the first button,
6th, 10th, 15th and more cards' background-color also changed.

I check the function called only once but it happens to several cards.
I assume this might be related to dequeueReusableCell cell but not sure...

can anybody please help me out?

```
 @objc func cardPressed(){
    changeCardBackground()
  }
  
  private func changeCardBackground(){
    var color:UIColor = .red
    
    if(isCardRed){
      color = .white
    }
    
    isCardRed = !isCardRed
  
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
      self.cardButton.backgroundColor = color
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableviewCells are reused you need to add `prepareForReuse` Method like :

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.cardButton.backgroundColor = defaultColor
}
```

Comment: oh man, you saved me.. it worked perfectly thank you!!

Comment: oh, I have one more question. other cards don't turn red when I tap the first card but when I scroll down and scroll to the top to see the first card, the background color of the first card becomes white again even if I don't tap it.. how can make the first card remain red?

Comment: You have to detect which button is clicked and control in it in cellForRowAt .